# Bash, variables and escaping symbols

Tags: linux, git, bash, ssh

I have a script that connects via SSH to test-server and retrieves the current Git branch. When I tried to use variables to print the branch and count of the number of modified files, I stack with escaping symbols.

This following works on a local folder:

```
mc=$(git status -s | grep -E '^[^?]+' -c);
branch=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/');
echo $branch \($mc\)
```

But this won't work:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.cron local.stage "cd /var/www && mc=$(git status -s | grep -E '^[^?]+' -c);
branch=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/');
echo $branch \($mc\)"
```

Comment: 1) use a heredoc instead of putting all your instructions on 1 line 2) What does `it won't work` mean ? Generally speaking, when you escape something using ssh, it means it will be interpretated on your remote machine. Otherwise, it is interpretated on the local one. Your problem might lie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things inside double quotes have variable expansion and command substitution performed.  So, for instance:

```
ssh remotehost "echo $(pwd)"
```

will get the other host to echo what `pwd` produces on the *local* host.  (I.e., the `$(pwd)` runs here first, then something like `echo /home/user/current/dir` is sent to the remote host, which dutifully echoes back the now-constant string.)

You need to prevent the command-substitution (in any suitable manner, for instance by using single quotes):

```
ssh remotehost 'echo $(pwd)'
```

which will pass the literal string `echo $(pwd)` to the remote host (where it will be acted-on by whatever shell you use on that host).

---

Aside from that, there are some minor improvements you can make to the command sequence:

- The [`git status` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) recommends using `--porcelain` instead of `--short` (`-s`) in scripts.
- To get the name of the current branch, use `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` (this is much simpler than using `git branch` and extracting the `*`-ed line and modifying it).

---

Putting these together and converting the inner quotes to double quotes (this is OK as there are no substitutions that will occur there):

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.cron local.stage 'cd /var/www &&
    mc=$(git status --porcelain | grep -E "^[^?]+" -c);
    branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD);
    echo $branch \($mc\)'
```

There is still a bug here: take note of the binding of the `&&` versus the semicolon.  If `/var/www` does not exist, this leaves `mc` unset and continues on to attempt to set `branch`.  (It's not a very consequential bug, but it's still not really right.)

Comment: Torek, thanks you very much for extended explanation. I found many interesting in your answer. And thanks again for complete solution.